# Problem with compiling c++ project that is running python code using Python.h -> undefined reference

Tags: python, c++, gcc, g++

I have problem when i try to compile my c++ project using g++ on windows

The code:

```
#include <python.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello World!')");
    Py_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am using this command:

`g++ -I C:\Python310\include main.cpp -o output -L C:\Python310\libs -lpython310`

And it always gives me this error about undefined references:

```
AppData\Local\Temp\ccQdtubj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_DecodeLocale'
AppData\Local\Temp\ccQdtubj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_SetProgramName'
AppData\Local\Temp\ccQdtubj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
AppData\Local\Temp\ccQdtubj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
AppData\Local\Temp\ccQdtubj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_FinalizeEx'
AppData\Local\Temp\ccQdtubj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_RawFree'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to link a program compiled with Windows `g++` (`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`)
against an import library `C:/Python310/libs/python310.lib` that was built with Micosoft MSVC.
That will not work because `x86_64-w64-mingw32` libraries are incompatible with MSVC libraries.
Get the [`x86_64-w64-mingw32` python library for MSYS2](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-python)
and build using its header files and libraries.

Consider installing and using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org)
as your working `gcc/g++` environment on Windows.

With that environment, a compile-and-link commandline (using the Windows filesystem) ought be like:

```
# Link with explicitly versioned import library 
g++ -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include\python3.11 main.cpp \
    -o output -L C:\msys64\mingw64\lib -lpython3.11
```

or:

```
# Link with unversioned import library 
g++ -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include\python3.11 main.cpp \
    -o output -L C:\msys64\mingw64\lib -lpython3
```

An import library in the msys64 environment is not called `name.lib` as per Windows but `libname.dll.a`,
`C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libpython3.dll.a` being for example the import library for `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.dll`

**Later**

@MatyVymlátil commented:

> I used the second command you gave me and it isn't giving me error about the python library,
> but about undefined reference to 'PyRun_SimpleStringFlags' and I don't know why.

It turns out that `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags` is undefined in `libpython3.dll.a` but is defined in `libpython3.11.dll.a`. Assuming (which appears to be true) that you have extended your `PATH` with `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-min\bin`, you can check things like this in Powershell like:

```
> nm C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libpython3.dll.a | findstr PyRun_SimpleStringFlags; echo Done
Done
```

in contrast with:

```
> nm C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libpython3.11.dll.a | findstr PyRun_SimpleStringFlags; echo Done
0000000000000000 I __imp_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags
0000000000000000 T PyRun_SimpleStringFlags
Done
```

Or in the MSYS2 shell ( = Linux bash) like:

```
$ nm /c/msys64/mingw64/lib/libpython3.dll.a | grep PyRun_SimpleStringFlags; echo Done
Done

$ nm /c/msys64/mingw64/lib/libpython3.11.dll.a | grep PyRun_SimpleStringFlags; echo Done
0000000000000000 I __imp_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags
0000000000000000 T PyRun_SimpleStringFlags
Done
```

See the [nm manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html)

That means you have to use the first command for a successful linkage. In Powershell

```
> g++ -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include\python3.11 main.cpp -o output -L C:\msys64\mingw64\lib -l python3.11
> .\output.exe
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Hello World!
```

Or in MSYS2 shell:

```
$  g++ -I /c/msys64/mingw64/include -I /c/msys64/mingw64/include/python3.11 main.cpp -o output -L /c/msys64/mingw64/lib -l python3.11
$ ./output.exe
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Hello World!
```

That warning:

```
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
```

will happen if you do not have the environment variables `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` set (correctly) in your
the shell environment in which `output.exe` is launched or more specifically the spawned environment is which your
program calls python.

You can set those variables and make the warning go away. In Powershell:

```
> $env:pythonhome = "C:\msys64\\mingw64\lib\"
> $env:pythonpath = "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11"
> .\output.exe
Hello World!
```

Or in MSYS2 shell:

```
$ export PYTHONHOME=/c/msys64/mingw64/lib
$ export PYTHONPATH=/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11
$ ./output.exe
Hello World!
```

And of course you can set these variables permanently in the Windows
settings for your user profile or the system profile.

You could also set those environment variables in your program itself
before calling `Py_Initialize`, but that would be unduly hard-coded.

Comment: OK, but i don't know if i'm doing it correctly. I installed MSYS2 and mingw-w64-x86_64-python package, but i don't know where i am supposed to find the python3.lib (python311.lib) libraries.

I edited the command a bit (i am using C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe now): 
g++ -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include\python3.11 main.cpp -o output -L C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11 -lpython311.

But it gives me this error:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython311
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status.

Comment: @MatyVymlátil. You're close! See updated answer.